# Is there a map of Kane's Earth that matches modern continents?

Tags: kane-the-mystic-swordsman

One of the things I always imagined about the Kane stories was that they were set in the deep prehistory of our own Earth -- thousands of years, perhaps, before what we know of as ancient civilization (Indus Valley, Mesopotamia, etc.) arose.  The last couple stories, however, confirm that Kane, who is both unaging and extremely tough, as well as highly skilled in many types of combat, has survived to the present day.

Still, I disbelieve that this is a deep enough span of time for the continents to change by more than could be accounted for by sea level rise or fall due to climate changes over millennia.  None the less, the only map I've ever seen of Kane's earth, showing places like Carsultyal and Lartroxia, doesn't match Earth's continents at all.

Is there a map available that shows the locations mentioned in the earlier Kane stories and books on the continents Earth has had for the past million years or so?

Comment: https://www.cartographersguild.com/attachment.php?s=e998299ad104604658ea583fcdb6cf0f&attachmentid=53145&d=1364702550

Comment: https://www.cartographersguild.com/attachment.php?s=e998299ad104604658ea583fcdb6cf0f&attachmentid=53146&d=1364702596

Comment: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ID-4IjCaXow/U8x0X2HHe7I/AAAAAAAAByI/85ODFbkJSBg/s1600/Kane-Map.jpg - Fan-made, according to Reddit

Comment: Tidier version of the map from the back of his anthology book; https://i.pinimg.com/474x/47/11/40/47114029e5027579a252e67d6dc8acd2--the-map-karl.jpg

Comment: The fan-made map on Blogspot is the one I've recently found.  My problem is that none of these have the continents Earth has had for longer than humans have existed.  I've imagined Thovnos being what we now call Maylasia, with the Northern and Southern continents being Eurasia and Africa.  Looks like I may have to make my own map...

Comment: According to Reddit, the problem may well be that the author originally situated the novels in a fictional land but only later decided it was set in the far future

Comment: Wait -- "far future"?  Kane is one of the first true humans, and the two "modern era" stories are set long after the ones that came out in the 1960/1970s.  Either way, in the last couple stories (which I haven't read) Kane is supposed to have gained the ability to cross dimensions, visiting Elric of Melnibone among other things.  Perhaps he found his way from his Earth to ours?